# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.slideToggle')

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error with this jQuery function.  Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.hideshow',function() {
        var t = $(this).id;
        t.slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I had two elements with the same name.  However, I simplified the function by adding a class to make it more universal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.hideshow',function() {
        $(".toggle").slideToggle();
    });
});
```